# Access a constructor property using javascript call function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to access a constructor's property using javascript call function.
EDIT: new example to clarify my thoughts :

```
Multiply = (function() {
    function Multiply() {
        this.multiplier = 10;
    }

    Multiply.prototype.multiply = function(number) {
        return number * this.multiplier;
    }

    return Multiply;

})();

Price = (function() {
    Price () {}

    Price.prototype.tenTimes = function(price) {
        console.log(Multiply.prototype.multiply.call(this, price);
    }

    return Price;
})()

var price = new Price();

price.tenTimes(10);
```

So, when running this code, I'll get undefined which I understand because of 'this' that doesn't reference the same object anymore.
So,is it even possible to do something like that. Is the new keyword the only solution to achieve this?

EDIT : I just want to know if I can avoid inheritance when I only want to use a single function of that constructor. You can imagine that the this.multiplier is some sort of configuration that I want to use everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually set up any inheritance there.

What you need is:

```
Person = (function() {
    function Person() {
        this.name = 'myname';
    }

    Person.prototype.say = function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }

    return Person;

})();

Person2 = (function() {
    function Person2() {}
    Person2.prototype = new Person(); // This is new

    Person2.prototype.hello = function() {
        this.say(); // This is new
    }


    return Person2;
})()


var person2 = new Person2();

person2.hello();
```

If you insist upon using `call`, you could do:

```
    Person2.prototype.hello = function() {
        Person2.prototype.say.call(this); // or Person....
    }
```

but that seems unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: I got it. But is it possible to access properties using the call function?